# how to use window.history with ajax calls

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, html5-history

I am working on an e-commerce website. Users can search for an item... let's say some user wants to buy an iPhone with max price = $200.

```
query: iPhone, maxPrice: $200
```

Now, what the system does is to send the above query in an ajax request to the server, server does the search and return the result which is displayed to the user.

The problem with the approach is that the page content gets updated, but the URL remains the same... (i.e. the url does not reflect that we are looking for an iPhone with maxPrice = $200)

So, what I have done is to update the URL once the ajax search is completed by calling this this function:

```
function updateUrl() {
    var newQuery = $('#filterForm').serialize();
    var newLocation = "";

    if (window.location.protocol) {
        newLocation = window.location.protocol + "//";
    }

    newLocation += window.location.host + window.location.pathname + "?" + newQuery;
    window.history.replaceState("", "search title", newLocation);        
}
```

This works perfect, user changes the search criteria, a new ajax request is sent to the server, the result is display and the url is updated to show the new search criteria. In This example the New URL would look like: 
`mySite/controller/action?query=iPhone&maxPrice=$200`

The only problem is that back button does not work correctly... let's say user fires to queries:

**Query-1:**
`mySite/controller/action?query=iPhone&maxPrice=$200`

**Query-2:**
`mySite/controller/action?query=samsung&maxPrice=$200`

Now if user press the back button, the url will change to Query-1, but the result displayed on the page does not get updated. I have to refresh the page after pressing back button to show the correct result.

Is there a better way (than refreshing the page after back button) to achieve this?

Comment: You can listen for the [onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) event and change the page based on the new URL.

Comment: @Titus: thanks. Are you suggesting that I listed to the onpopstate event, and when the back button is fired, grab the url from the history and fire a new ajax request to update the page content?

Comment: When `onpopstate` is triggered, `location` will be changed to the previous URL (no need to get the URL from history).

Comment: @Titus: Sorry, that's what I mean... when back button is clicked, the location is updated (but the page content is not). Are you suggesting that I should fire a new Ajax request to the server with the new location (as you said the location gets updated on back button click)? I have tried `pushState` and in both cases, the browser URL is correctly updated but I need to hit F5 for the page content to be refreshed.

Comment: managing history is a pain, I like to use this minimal JS router to make it easier https://github.com/krasimir/navigo

Comment: Yes, you can even keep your own history (the previous page content) and use that instead of making a new AJAX call.